Why does unity dosent work when i run "while (Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.time / 0.6f) % 16 == 0)"?
I'm trying to make a drum machine in unity, and I separated time into 16 slots in which if the person chooses to, he can save a variable from 1 to 6 (representing 6 different sounds) and everytime that we get to that slot, it i'll play that 1 to 6 sound.
I found that i can use Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.time / 0.6f) % 16 for an general way to keep track of time and always be in the correct slot.
Outside of a while command, with something like this:
 void Update()
   {
       slot = Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.time / 0.6f) % 16;
       Debug.Log("The time is" + Time.time + " and it is in " + slot);

   }

it works perfectly, it returns the right time and the slot keeps changing, (0, 1, 2, 3... then back to 0) but if i use something like this
while (Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.time / 0.6f) % 16 == 0)
{
Debug.Log(Time.time);
}


or
while (slot == 0)
        {
            slot = Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.time / 0.6f) % 16;
        }

unity gets stuck on startup, saying that it is "waiting for unity code to finish exectuing" in "application.enterplaymode" do you guys have any idea why? I'm also accepting suggestions on other approaches that i could use.
Thanks in advance.
here's the whole code for reference:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Lógica : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int slotAtual;


//was going to use this variables for visual control, but didn't got to this yet
    public GameObject MII;
    public GameObject MI;
    public GameObject MKICK;
    public GameObject SNARE;
    public GameObject MTOM;
    public GameObject MTOM2;
    public GameObject MOOH;
    public GameObject MCHH;
    public GameObject M2SNARE;
    public GameObject M2TOM;
    public GameObject M2TOM2;
    public GameObject M2OHH;
    public GameObject M2CHH;
    public int MIIi = 0;
    public int MIi = 0;
    public int MKICKi = 0;
    public int SNAREi = 0;
    public int MTOMi = 0;
    public int MTOM2i = 0;
    public int MOOHi = 0;
    public int MCHHi = 0;
    public int M2SNAREi = 0;
    public int M2TOMi = 0;
    public int M2TOM2i = 0;
    public int M2OHHi = 0;
    public int M2CHHi = 0;

    public int f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16;

    public int b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16;

    public AudioSource soundPlayer;

    private float tempoDecorrido = 0f;
    private float tempoInicial;

    public AudioClip[] sons;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        while (slotAtual == 0)
        {
            slotAtual = Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.time / 0.6f) % 16;
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)) { b1 = 1; }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X)) { b1 = 2; }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)) { b1 = 3; }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B)) { b1 = 4; }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N)) { b1 = 5; }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M)) { b1 = 6; }
            if (b1 != 0)
            {
                AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(sons[b1 - 1], transform.position);
            }
        }
    }

    }

i did try to remove everything but the part i'm having trouble with, still the same problem. Also tried to start a new project to no avail.

because the loop you make never allows anything else to happen...

The function Time.time return the time value at the begining of the frame. So inside the while the Time.time is never Update as long as the frame never end cause of infinite loop.
Reference here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html .
I think for what you are trying to do you should use a coroutine https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html .

Thanks, Gabriel, I didn't know that "while" stopped updating frames in the code and that time.time used frames to update itself.
I also didn't know about the coroutine function either, I started watching some videos about it and I think it will help! Thanks!
